# Problems with installing jcc and pylucene

Tags: java, python, pylucene, jcc

I'm trying to install pylucene on Windows XP.
I installed JDK on C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.6.0_18 .
I also installed Visual Studio C++ Express to have a C++ compiler.

As first step I'm trying to integrate jcc into python2.6 through the command: C:\Python26\python.exe setup.py build

This gives me the following result:

```
C:\Installfiles\pylucene-3.0.1-1\jcc>C:\Python26\python.exe setup.py build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 332, in <module>
    main('--debug' in sys.argv)
  File "setup.py", line 289, in main
    raise type(e), "%s: %s" %(e, args)
WindowsError: [Error 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden: ['jav
ac.exe', '-d', 'jcc/classes', 'java/org/apache/jcc/PythonVM.java', 'java/org/apa
che/jcc/PythonException.java']
```

Other information:

In systems I set:

Uservariables:

CLASSPATH

C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin\javac.exe

System Variables

Path

%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem; C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin

Where does the error come from and what do I have to do to overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

Is there really a space in "jav ac.exe", as shown in the error message? Can setup.py just call javac.exe (is the java binaries directory in the PATH?)

Disclaimer: I've built jcc and pylucene on mac os x and linux, but not on windows.

Comment: It's a line break instead of a space I think.

I have added as I wrote above C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin which is the java binaries directory to Path (does it have to be capitalized?)